# Difference between decorating a property in C# with BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId) vs BsonId vs ObjectId

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

Am new to mongodb and am liking how easy it is not to worry about schema stuff, I have a question suppose you want an Id property in mongo and mongo uses `ObjectId` to denote property Id's, so far i see you can have or decorate an Id as follows,

```
public ObjectId Id {get; set;}

//or

[BsonId]
public string Id {get; set;}

//or

[BsonId]
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
public string Id {get; set;}
```

Can anyone explain to me why most people choose the last type, and whats going on and how the flexibility helps. Thanks?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

1. If you have a column named `Id, id or _id`, in your strongly typed `TDocument` class (the item type in a collection), then a column named `"_id"` will be generated in Mongo. It will also create an index for that column. You get a `duplicate key error` exception if trying to insert an item with a key that already exists.

---

```
public ObjectId Id {get; set;}
```

will use the type generator for `ObjectId` and it will look like

```
_id: ObjectId("57ade20771e59f422cc652d9")
```

Likewise:

```
public Guid _id { get; set; }
```

will use the Guid generator to produce smth like

```
"_id" : BinData(3,"s2Td7qdghkywlfMSWMPzaA==")
```

Also all of the following properties

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string id { get; set; }
public byte[] _id { get; set; }
```

will be index columns using the defaults for each type if not specified.

2. `[BsonId]` gives you the flexibility of naming that index any way you want.

---

These both will be indexes:

```
[BsonId] 
public Guid SmthElseOtherThanId { get; set; } 

[BsonId] 
public string StringId { get; set; }
```

However;

```
public Guid SmthElseOtherThanId { get; set; } 
public string StringId { get; set; }
```

won't be indexes, mongodb will still use `_id` internally.

Same logic,

```
public ObjectId SmthElseOtherThanId {get; set;}
```

with no `[BsonId]` decoration won't be an index column.

3. `[BsonRepresentation]` lets you juggle with the Mongo type vs the internal .Net type, *if there's a conversion between them*.

Having

```
[BsonId] 
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)] 
public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
```

is identical to:

```
public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
```

But,

```
[BsonId] 
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)] 
public string Id { get; set; }
```

is different. Mongo will auto generate object ids by itself, however you will be able to use strings in .net, filter queries etc., because there is a conversion between  object id and string.

Having

```
[BsonId] 
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)] 
public byte[] Id { get; set; }
```

or

```
[BsonId] 
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)] 
public int Id { get; set; }
```

will fail with a `ObjectId not a valid representation for a ByteArraySerializer / Int32Serializer` message.

But

```
[BsonId] 
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)] 
public int StringId { get; set; }
```

will be just fine.

Comment: Thanks ,any performance penalty's experienced  for type conversions,is it noticeable at scale.