# MongoDB C#/.NET Driver - How to deserialize UUID and ISODate

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, deserialization, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a document in a MongoDB collection like so:

```
{
  _id: new UUID("31daac77-bcbc-4cd5-bb93-382440f46f16"),
  CompanyId: 'XYZ',
  RequestDate: ISODate("2023-01-10T07:52:32.840Z")
}
```

It corresponds to an object like so:

```cs
public class ReportRequest
{
    public ReportRequest(string companyId)
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        this.CompanyId = companyId;
        this.RequestDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    [BsonId]
    [BsonElement("_id")]
    [BsonGuidRepresentation(GuidRepresentation.Standard)]
    public Guid Id { get; }

    [BsonElement]
    public string CompanyId { get; }

    [BsonElement]
    [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Utc)]
    public DateTime RequestDate { get; }
}
```

I then try to query for all documents with a particular `CompanyId`:

```cs
public async Task PrintAvailableReportDatesAsync(string companyId)
{
    var filter = Builders<ReportRequest>.Filter.Eq(r => r.CompanyId, companyId);
    var cursor = await _collection.FindAsync(filter);
    var reportRequests = await cursor.ToListAsync();

    foreach (var req in reportRequests)
        Console.WriteLine($"Id: {req.Id.ToString()}, Date: {req.RequestDate}");
}
```

I would expect to get the following output:

> Id: 31daac77-bcbc-4cd5-bb93-382440f46f16, Date: 2023-01-10T07:52:32.840Z

Instead, I get this:

> Id: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, Date: 0001-01-01T00:00:00

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need to add BsonElement attribute to the prop if the name is matching. If you do so, the name of the property must be added like you did with [BsonElement("_id")].

Comment: Regarding [BsonGuidRepresentation(GuidRepresentation.Standard)] read this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38871416/difference-between-decorating-a-property-in-c-sharp-with-bsonrepresentationbson

Comment: @RaduHatos Maybe wonky behavior from the library, but if I do not add the BsonElement attribute to those others, I find that those fields are completely skipped for some reason when I use the `InsertOneAsync()` method. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I tested on my local side, those properties' values were assigned within the constructor.

There are 2 approaches to fix it:

**Approach 1: Provide the setter to all properties**

```cs
public class ReportRequest
{
    public ReportRequest(string companyId)
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        this.CompanyId = companyId;
        this.RequestDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    [BsonId]
    [BsonGuidRepresentation(GuidRepresentation.Standard)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string CompanyId { get; set; }

    [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Utc)]
    public DateTime RequestDate { get; set; }
}
```

> Demo

[image]

---

**Approach 2: Create a constructor with three parameters**

```cs
public class ReportRequest
{
    ...

    public ReportRequest(Guid id, string companyId, DateTime requestDate)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.CompanyId = companyId;
        this.RequestDate = requestDate;
    }

    ...
}
```

> Demo

[image]

Comment: I opted to add a second constructor. I had to decorate it with a `[BsonConstructor]` attribute, but it worked. Thank you.